# Admob mediation native advance ads not serve Facebook audience network ads

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

Only show admob ads. waiting for 2 days.
I set priority to FAN but no any Facebook audience network ad requests. Need additional code for native ads request ?

```
private void loadNativeAds() {
    mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();
    AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
            new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                    // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                    // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                    mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                        insertAdsInMenuItems();
                    }
                }
            }).withAdListener(
            new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                    // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                        insertAdsInMenuItems();
                    }
                }
            }).build();

    // Load the Native ads.
    adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
}
```

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start),

> The `loadAds()` method currently works only with AdMob ads. For mediated ads, use `loadAd()` instead.

Changing `adLoader.loadAds()` to `adLoader.loadAd()` should start loading Facebook Audience Network native ads.

Comment: So in app feed "list" we should load one by one to serve mediation! It seems horrible to do so.